# toBe(true) vs toBeTruthy() vs toBeTrue()

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-matchers

What is the difference between `expect(something).toBe(true)`, `expect(something).toBeTruthy()` and `expect(something).toBeTrue()`?

Note that `toBeTrue()` is a *custom matcher* introduced in [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) among other useful and handy matchers like `toHaveMethod()` or `toBeArrayOfStrings()`.

---

The question is meant to be generic, but, as a real-world example, I'm testing that an element is displayed in `protractor`. Which matcher should I use in this case?

```
expect(elm.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
expect(elm.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
expect(elm.isDisplayed()).toBeTrue();
```

Comment: i thinks `.toBe(true)`==`.toBeTrue()`. toBeTruthy() can be true not only upon _true_, but upon _123_, "dfgdfg", [1,2,3], etc... basically `if(x==true)` are truthy, while `if(x===true)` are true true.

Comment: That will depend on what the value you are testing is.  Use `toBeTruthy` if you are unsure of the type it is the same as `== true` while I suspect `.toBe(true)` is the same as `=== true` Mind you its a little overboard to call a function to test for true. Word of advice,. Forget `==` and `!=` exists in Javascript and never use it again. Truthy is not needed and a trap for beginers. Use `===` and `!==` instead.

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks for the advice, it makes perfect sense. We even have `eslint` reporting us if `==` or `!=` are used suggesting to change it to `===` and `!==`.

Answer (score 336, accepted):

What I do when I wonder something like the question asked here is go to the source.

#### toBe()

[`expect().toBe()`](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/4097718b6682f643833f5435b63e4f590f22919f/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L2779) is defined as:

```
function toBe() {
  return {
    compare: function(actual, expected) {
      return {
        pass: actual === expected
      };
    }
  };
}
```

It performs its test with `===` which means that when used as `expect(foo).toBe(true)`, it will pass only if `foo` actually has the value `true`. Truthy values won't make the test pass.

#### toBeTruthy()

[`expect().toBeTruthy()`](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/4097718b6682f643833f5435b63e4f590f22919f/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L2908) is defined as:

```
function toBeTruthy() {
  return {
    compare: function(actual) {
      return {
        pass: !!actual
      };
    }
  };
}
```

#### Type coercion

A value is truthy if the coercion of this value to a boolean yields the value `true`. The operation `!!` tests for truthiness by coercing the value passed to `expect` to a boolean. Note that contrarily to what the currently accepted answer [implies](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32615803/2), `== true` is **not** a correct test for truthiness. You'll get funny things like

```
> "hello" == true
false
> "" == true
false
> [] == true
false
> [1, 2, 3] == true
false
```

Whereas using `!!` yields:

```
> !!"hello"
true
> !!""
false
> !![1, 2, 3]
true
> !![] 
true
```

(Yes, empty or not, an array is truthy.)

#### toBeTrue()

`expect().toBeTrue()` is part of [Jasmine-Matchers](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) (which is registered on npm as `jasmine-expect` after a later project registered `jasmine-matchers` first).

[`expect().toBeTrue()`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers/blob/e02982ea40d85761f9d0a9eae8358512a6fad133/src/toBeTrue.js#L7-L11) is defined as:

```
function toBeTrue(actual) {
  return actual === true ||
    is(actual, 'Boolean') &&
    actual.valueOf();
}
```

The difference with `expect().toBeTrue()` and `expect().toBe(true)` is that `expect().toBeTrue()` tests whether it is dealing with a `Boolean` object. `expect(new Boolean(true)).toBe(true)` would fail whereas `expect(new Boolean(true)).toBeTrue()` would pass. This is because of this funny thing:

```
> new Boolean(true) === true
false
> new Boolean(true) === false
false
```

At least it is truthy:

```
> !!new Boolean(true)
true
```

#### Which is best suited for use with `elem.isDisplayed()`?

Ultimately Protractor hands off this request to Selenium. The [documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/module_selenium-webdriver_class_WebElement.html) states that the value produced by `.isDisplayed()` is a promise that resolves to a `boolean`. I would take it at face value and use `.toBeTrue()` or `.toBe(true)`. If I found a case where the implementation returns truthy/falsy values, I would file a bug report.

Answer (score 41):

> **Disclamer**: This is just a wild guess

I know everybody loves an easy-to-read list:

- `toBe(<value>)` - The returned value is the same as `<value>`
- `toBeTrue()` - Checks if the returned value is `true`
- `toBeTruthy()` - Check if the value, when cast to a boolean, will be a truthy value

  Truthy values are all values that aren't `0`, `''` (empty string), `false`, `null`, `NaN`, `undefined` or `[]` (empty array)*.

  <sub>* Notice that when you run `!![]`, it returns `true`, but when you run `[] == false` it also returns `true`. It depends on how it is implemented. In other words: `(!![]) === ([] == false)`</sub>

---

On your example, `toBe(true)` and `toBeTrue()` will yield the same results.

Comment: An empty array is falsey.

Comment: @MicahWilliamson Thanks! Fixed the answer

Comment: empty arrays are 100% truthy in JS `alert(!![])`

Comment: @dandavis `[] == true` in your console produces `false`. `[] == false` in you console produces `true`

Comment: @MicahWilliamson: that's because your'e comparing the string version of the array (empty string) to true. it can be confusing...

Comment: @dandavis The results would be the same

Comment: Fixed the answer now.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Not sure what you mean by the note in your asterisk. `true (true)`, `!true (false)`, `!!true (true)`. I don't think it's a different implementation- it follows the same rules.

Comment: @MicahWilliamson What I'm saying is that `(!![]) === ([] == false)`.

Comment: @Downvoters - Please, explain **why!?** the downvotes so I can fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: @kjhughes You are almost 5 years late. The answer will stay untouched.

Comment: Your [comment asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615713/tobetrue-vs-tobetruthy-vs-tobetrue#comment53725821_32615835) why you were being downvoted.  Thought you might still appreciate an explanation (don't post "wild guesses").  Anyway, at this point, keep in mind that answers are arguably more for future readers than for original askers, so it's never too late to improve your answer from "just a wild guess" to a definitive answer.

Answer (score 29):

In javascript there are trues and truthys. When something is true it is obviously true or false. When something is truthy it may or may not be a boolean, but the "cast" value of is a boolean.

Examples.

```
true == true; // (true) true
1 == true; // (true) truthy
"hello" == true;  // (true) truthy
[1, 2, 3] == true; // (true) truthy
[] == false; // (true) truthy
false == false; // (true) true
0 == false; // (true) truthy
"" == false; // (true) truthy
undefined == false; // (true) truthy
null == false; // (true) truthy
```

This can make things simpler if you want to check if a string is set or an array has any values.

```
var users = [];

if(users) {
  // this array is populated. do something with the array
}

var name = "";

if(!name) {
  // you forgot to enter your name!
}
```

And as stated. `expect(something).toBe(true)` and `expect(something).toBeTrue()` is the same. But `expect(something).toBeTruthy()` is not the same as either of those.

Comment: `[] == false;` is not correct, the statement itself is false because objects are always truthy

Comment: @dandavis Not true. Objects aren't always truthy. But that statement `[] == false;` is `true`

Comment: ok, you got me, let me correct myself. built-in object besides _null_ are always truthy... `[]` is truthy though.

Comment: @dandavis Yes. Not sure why arrays are treated differently- perhaps it's the string explanation you made. Either way it's pretty useful

Comment: no, it's not useful, just the opposite in fact: it's a noob gotcha... consider `[""]==false` or `[0]== false`; not empty, not falsey, just deceptive...

Comment: Interesting. Probably should stick to `if(users.length)` then

Comment: Using `x == true` as you have in your examples is a misleading and, as the above comments show, incorrect way to illustrate the concept of truthiness in JavaScript. The real test of truthiness in JavaScript is how a value behaves in an `if` statement or as an operand in a boolean expression. We know `1` is truthy because `if (1)` will cause the next statement to be evaluated. Likewise `[]` is truthy for the same reason: Even though `[] == true` evaluates to `false`, `if ([])` will still cause the next statement to be evaluated, so we know `[]` is truthy.

Comment: You should use === to compare, not ==, so I don't believe your example to be trustworthy.

Answer (score 8):

As you read through the examples below, just keep in mind this difference

```
true === true // true
"string" === true // false
1 === true // false
{} === true // false
```

But

```
Boolean("string") === true // true
Boolean(1) === true // true
Boolean({}) === true // true
```

### 1. expect(statement).toBe(true)

Assertion passes when the statement passed to `expect()` evaluates to `true`

```
expect(true).toBe(true) // pass
expect("123" === "123").toBe(true) // pass
```

In all other cases cases it would fail

```
expect("string").toBe(true) // fail
expect(1).toBe(true); // fail
expect({}).toBe(true) // fail
```

Even though all of these statements would evaluate to `true` when doing `Boolean()`:

So you can think of it as 'strict' comparison

### 2. expect(statement).toBeTrue()

This one does exactly the same type of comparison as `.toBe(true)`, but was introduced in Jasmine recently in version `3.5.0` on Sep 20, 2019

### 3. expect(statement).toBeTruthy()

`toBeTruthy` on the other hand, evaluates the output of the statement into boolean first and then does comparison

```
expect(false).toBeTruthy() // fail
expect(null).toBeTruthy() // fail
expect(undefined).toBeTruthy() // fail
expect(NaN).toBeTruthy() // fail
expect("").toBeTruthy() // fail
expect(0).toBeTruthy() // fail
```

And IN ALL OTHER CASES it would pass, for example

```
expect("string").toBeTruthy() // pass
expect(1).toBeTruthy() // pass
expect({}).toBeTruthy() // pass
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot many good answers out there, i just wanted to add a scenario where the usage of these expectations might be helpful. Using `element.all(xxx)`, if i need to check if all elements are displayed at a single run, i can perform -

```
expect(element.all(xxx).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy(); //Expectation passes
expect(element.all(xxx).isDisplayed()).toBe(true); //Expectation fails
expect(element.all(xxx).isDisplayed()).toBeTrue(); //Expectation fails
```

Reason being `.all()` returns an array of values and so all kinds of expectations(`getText`, `isPresent`, etc...) can be performed with `toBeTruthy()` when `.all()` comes into picture. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice! I remember `reduce()`-ing the array of booleans into a single value and then applying the `toBe(true)` check. This is much simpler, thank you.